# How to display a message to the client using wso2 esb mediators

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Hi I have created an custom sequence with a switch and dblookup mediators. In one of the cases I'd like to display a message to the client. I tried Respond Mediators but it does not output any message when invoking the API using cURL. I'm just getting HTTP OK. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying localhost...
* Connected to localhost (localhost) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /drewtest/1.0/users/103 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:8280
> Authorization: Bearer 53f983bc15a4b19e5d929fba4d4e9ada
> Accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8280
< Accept: application/json
< Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 03:29:24 GMT
* Server WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP is not blacklisted
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, create a custom message using `payload mediator` and then use `<respond>` mediator. It will send the message to client. Try with SOAPUI.

```
    Eg: 
    <Sequence>

     <Your case>
    <payload>
    It will construct the required message to be sent back to client
    </payload>
    <respond> //Will send that message to client

    </Yourcase>
 </Sequence>
```

Comment: is it possible to set static values for the message in the payload mediator

Comment: Yes you can . What you define in payload mediator will overwrite the current message which flows through the sequence.